How should I start with DnD?
I've been meaning to try out DnD for a while. I will go next time the DnD club meets at school, but what should I do to prepare? Should I watch some videos on YouTube? (sorry if this is a stupid question lol) Also for what edition I have no idea what kind they play (I can ask my friend who goes tho if that will help) The main thing I want to know is how to make my first character and if there's anything I need to get before playing. The only dice I have are a ton of D6 and some (I think 3) D20s. (EDIT: we play D&D beyond)

Hi Pengu and Welcome to the stack.  Please check out the links that Kyan and I put in the comments.  I expect your question will be closed soon, but after you read the other questions, if you have anything further to ask you can post again, asking a new and more specific question.

Your edit is very helpful, but to answer that we would need to know the editon your group is playing. The most common and recent editon is 5E, which has two versions a 2014 one and a 2024 one that was just released.
That being said your friend who plays or their GM should be able to answer all of your questions for you.

he said we play D&D Byond

Beyond*   my badd

D&D Beyond is a website, it supports both 5e versions. You can even create characters there or select pre existing ones and you can roll dice with it if you use the app. Check it out for yourself, it might be just what you need to get started.

Thanks! I didnt know that
